# Override TStringList.Delimiter

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

TStringList.Delimiter is a TChar. This make it possible to have Delimitertext as

```
Test,Test,Test,Test
```

But I want to have ' and ' as Delimiter with the result

```
Test and Test and Test and Test
```

Of course I can solve it like this

```
s := List[0];
for i := 1 to List.Count - 1 do
  s := s + ' and ' + List[i];
```

But it would be more elegant to do

```
List.Delimiter := ' and ';
s := List.DelimiterText;
```

So I try this code to override TStringList;

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels, cxLookAndFeelPainters, cxContainer, cxEdit, Menus, StdCtrls, cxButtons, cxTextEdit,
  cxMemo;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    cxMemo1: TcxMemo;
    cxButton1: TcxButton;
    procedure cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TAttracsStringList = class(TStringList)
  private
    FDelimiter: String;
    procedure SetDelimiter(const Value: String);
    function GetDelimiter: String;
  public
    property Delimiter: String read GetDelimiter write SetDelimiter;
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function TAttracsStringList.GetDelimiter: String;
begin
  Result := FDelimiter;
end;

procedure TAttracsStringList.SetDelimiter(const Value: String);
begin
  FDelimiter := Value;
end;

procedure TForm5.cxButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vList: TAttracsStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  vList := TAttracsStringList.Create;
  try
    vList.Delimiter := ' and ';
    for i := 0 to 3 do
      vList.Add('Test');

    cxMemo1.Text := vList.DelimitedText;
  finally
    vList.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

It don't work. The memo got result

```
Test,Test,Test,Test
```

How can I fix this ?

**Edit**
I see now that GetDelimiter and SetDelimiter is private in TStringList. So I cannot override them. Wonder if there is a way to achieve what I want ?

**Edit2**
I solved it by add

```
property DelimitedText: String read GetDelimitedText;
```

with method

```
function TAttracsStringList.GetDelimitedText: String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Count > 0 then
  begin
    Result := Strings[0];

    for i := 1 to Count - 1 do
      Result := Result + Delimiter + Strings[i];
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

So if someone don't have a more clever way I consider this as solved.

Comment: Roll your own code for this

Comment: Why would you want to override `Get/SetDelimiter`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stringlist with delimiter as a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297987/stringlist-with-delimiter-as-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed another solution:

```
  lst := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for I := 1 to 4 do
      lst.Add('Test');
    lst.LineBreak := ' and ';
    Writeln(lst.Text);
  finally
    lst.Free;
  end;
```

As a drawback the individual entries are not quoted.

Comment: Thanks, very clever!
I hope that can work instead of Delimiter.

Comment: Unfortunately Linebreak don't work either as linebreak is added last in the string